# Restrict method to accept resource resolved by ContextCompat

Tags: java, android, android-library

I have a model for which one of the setters is expecting a [Color Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) but it is not to able use said resource directly without it being resolved (by making use of [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)).

Is there a way that I can annotate my method to indicate/restrict this?

```
public class SimpleModel {
    private String name;
    private int bgColor;
    private int bgImage;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBgColor() {
        return bgColor;
    }

    public void setBgColor(@ColorInt final int bgColor) {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
    }

    public int getBgImage() {
        return bgImage;
    }

    public void setBgImage(@DrawableRes final int bgImage) {
        this.bgImage = bgImage;
    }
}
```

I'm aware of [`@ColorRes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorRes.html) and [`@ColorInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorInt.html) -- but they don't fully resolve my issue.

Is this something that an annotation can take care of for me? What about JavaDocs?

If not -- how can I check that the resource being passed is usable?

Comment: "I have a model for which one of the setters is expecting a Color Resource" -- that is not the model in your question, near as I can tell. You are accepting a `@ColorInt` (which is already resolved) and a `@DrawableRes` (which is not a color resource).

Comment: @CommonsWare So there is no way to restrict a user from just sending `R.color.red` instead of `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red);`
I realize that I didn't structure this question as best as I could.

Comment: "So there is no way to restrict a user from just sending R.color.red instead of ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)" -- that specific comparison should be caught by `@ColorInt`. `R.color.red` is not a color integer, but a color resource ID. So, with the code in your question, I would expect `model.setBgColor(R.color.red)` to result in a Lint error, while `model.setBgColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red))` would not.

Comment: Got it -- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ColorRes` denotes a requirement that the parameter be a color resource ID.

`@ColorInt`, in effect, is `@!ColorRes`, if applying a "not" operator were possible with annotations. It denotes a requirement that the parameter be an `int` that is not a color resource ID.

So, your `public void setBgColor(@ColorInt final int bgColor)` method should result in the following:

- `model.setBgColor(R.color.red)` : Lint error
- `model.setBgColor(getColor(R.color.red))` : no errors
- `model.setBgColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red))` : no errors

If, for some reason, you need to distinguish between the latter two scenarios... I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down like that -- very easy to understand this way!